# ScrollView com uma view estática no meio

Tags: android, mobile, rolamento, android-recyclerview

Eu tenho esse layout no qual eu preciso implementar um ScrollView mas não consigo ajustar de uma maneira correta, eu preciso que o Scrollview contemple a parte azul e amarela, ai o usuário pode ver o resto dos itens que tiverem no recyclerview. Porem assim que ele deslizar o "static textview" precisa subir e ficar sempre visivel na tela, como mostra na segunda imagem, alguem tem idéia de como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: Pós scroll]

Comment: Você já tentou fazer assim.... pega 3 linear layout, monta de acordo com o que voce quer (horizontal ou vertical) e posiciona um embaixo do outro, de acordo com a imagem vai ficar em segundo e no segundo vc coloca um scroll nele com o conteudo dentro... não sei mas pode funcionar dessa maneira, tomara que ajude você. **isso é uma ideia**

Comment: Voce quer fazer estilo esse gif aqui? http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: Obrigado pelos replies, esse esquema com os 3 linear layouts não funciona, porque o scrollview precisa englobar tudo, exceto essa view do meio.

@Mr_Anderson eu pensei em usar o coordinator, mas no caso aqui nao temos uma toolbar e essa view static não subirá para o lugar da toolbar, ela ficaria abaixo.